# Trouble with RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep of Spark job running in Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running Spark Streaming job in Google Dataproc Cluster. I want to test the case what happens Dataproc abruptly stops/fails while streaming job is still running. Hence I stopped the Dataproc cluster manually while the job is still running,

I got the below info in log once I stopped,

```
22/10/12 06:46:39 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: airflow-stream-test-m/10.***:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
22/10/12 06:46:39 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: airflow-stream-test-m/10.***:8030. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
22/10/12 06:46:40 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: airflow-stream-test-m/10.***:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
22/10/12 06:46:40 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: airflow-stream-test-m/10.***:8030. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
22/10/12 06:46:41 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: airflow-stream-test-m/10.***:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
22/10/12 06:46:41 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: airflow-stream-test-m/10.***:8030. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

The problem is the job just hangs right here. `RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep` never reaches the count `10`. Hence the job's status is just shown as '`running`' in dataproc console. But I want the job to fail.

Is there any way to reduce `RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep`? I want to reduce it to `2`. Also I don't understand why job hangs and `RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep` doesn't increment to `10`.

Comment: Can you try adding retry policy as `RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=2, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)`? Are you getting any other error messages?

Comment: Where is that policy? How do I specify while submitting the spark job?

Comment: When submitting the job can you try not specifying `max restarts` so that job will fail without restarting the job? Also, can you retry submitting the job and if it's still failing can you provide the command you are using?

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.